# Improve MS Office interop performance for smart arts

Tags: c#, performance, tree, ms-office, office-interop

I am using MS Office interop to create a visualization of an internal data structure. The data is structured like a tree and I use the according smart art. This is how I create the smart art:

```
Word._Application oWord;
Word._Document oDoc;
oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = true;
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add();

oDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
var smartArt = oDoc.Shapes.AddSmartArt(oDoc.Application.SmartArtLayouts[98], 0, 0, 700, 450).SmartArt;
var root = smartArt.Nodes.Add();
var parent = root.ParentNode;
root.Promote();
//Deletes nodes that have been created by default
DeleteTree(parent); 
//Fills the smart art node with the data of my internal structure
FillNode(root, myInternalRoot); 


void FillNode(SmartArtNode saNode, InternalNode node)
{                                    
    foreach (var c in node.Children)
    {
        FillNode(saNode.AddNode(MsoSmartArtNodePosition.msoSmartArtNodeBelow), c);
    }
}
```

This code successfully creates the visualization. However, the more nodes I insert into the tree, the slower the creation gets. The first nodes are quite fast, but then you can watch them getting slower and slower. A quite small tree with about 100 nodes takes about 45 seconds to build. Bigger trees take a whole lot more time.

I assume the reason for that is Word's layout algorithm. It probably executes every time a new node is added. Is there a way to improve the performance? I was thinking of something similar like `SuspendLayout` in WinForms. Kind of:

```
DontTryToLayout();
AddNodes();
LayoutNow();
```

I also tried to set `oWord.Visible` after creating the smart art. But that doesn't help.

Here is a screenshot of the created tree:

[image: Tree Visualization]

Comment: Just a suggestion, i do not really know whether it works: Do not set the document visibility, but the visibility of the SmartArt itself to false before invoking *FillNode(root, ...)*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the smart art object does not have an according property or method.

Comment: Maybe misunderstanding. According to documentation, *oDoc.Shapes.AddSmartArt()* returns a *Shape* object (which you have named in your code "smartArt"). This shape object stored in the variable "smartArt" has a *Visible* property. (Or is the documentation wrong and AddSmartArt does not return a Shape object, perhaps?)

Comment: I see. I used the shape's `SmartArt` and this object does not have a `Visible` property. However, disabling the shape's visibility makes it invisible, but not faster.

Comment: Darn. Sorry that i cannot be more helpful. While I don't know what makes the SmartArt so slow, i can see that you add nodes in a depth-first manner. Although it will be more implementation effort, you might try adding nodes breadth-first/in level-order. (However, i want to reemphasize that i really don't know whether or not this would affect performance significantly in any way. I am really just poking in the dark here, and chances are pretty high that these efforts might just be a waste...)

Comment: Office Interop is notoriously slow. Instead of trying to understand the inner workings of Office, why not perform this with OpenXML?